# Badly displayed accented characters

Tags: typo3, character, display, diacritics

On a CMS TYPO3 website I created 15-20 years ago and have been updating regularly, a few days ago, noticed  a new problem:   that the accented characters were all displayed badly.  I hadn't changed or updated anything for a few weeks.  How do I get it back to how it was?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bad UTF-8 encoding of your database.
Normaly this should have been detected and cleared some years ago when TYPO3 switched over to UTF-8 connections in general. Up to then it was possible to use the database in any encoding and force UTF-8 usage in the connection. in this way UTF-8 characters were stored in e.g. iso-latin fields. one missing forced usage and you ended up with a scrambled page. especially if you transfered the data with a dump you could destroy your data.

As this should have been happened years ago, another problem could have occured:
Maybe your (updated?) browser can't decide which encoding your site is using and guessed wrong.
Maybe you need to provide a proper encoding information in your HTML output.

---

ADD:
A proper encoding information may look like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` or just `<meta charset="utf-8">` as meta information in the HTML header.
Normaly such a header is sent by TYPO3 by default.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for the info!  How do I provide a proper encoding information in your HTML output?    I am not much of computer wiz.